# Python nested json parsing and splitting the values

Tags: python, json

I am trying to split and assign the url's to the variable, I am getting the desired result but I know there is a way where I can improvise the current code.

JSON FILE

```
{
"Result": [
    "Url::Link::Url1",
    "Url::Link::Url2",
    "Url::Link::Url3",
    "Url::Link::Url4",
    "Url::Link::Url5",
    "Url::Link::Url6",
    "Url::Link::Url7"
],
"Record": [
    "Record::Label::Music1",
    "Record::Label::Music2",
    "Record::Label::Music3"
],
}
```

```
import requests
import json

url = "http:mywebsite.com"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
    }

result= requests.get("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
url1 = []
url2 = []
url3 = []

for i in result['Result'][0:1]:
    url1.append(i.split('::')[2])

for i in result['Result'][1:2]:
    url1.append(i.split('::')[2])

for i in result['Result'][2:3]:
    url1.append(i.split('::')[2])
```

Output
url1=Url1
url2=Url2
...

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: it may be better to post your question in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Don't forget to add your own code.

Comment: Having trouble in pasting the code

Comment: @rusu_ro1 Added the code

Comment: each for should have url1, url2, url3... ?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 yes I want to assign each URL1 to the variable url1 and similarly URL2 to url2

Comment: @Nik what about to hold all urls in a list ?like in my example?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use list comprehension:

```
>>> urls = [i.split('::')[2]
...             for _ in range(len(result['Result']))
...             for i in result['Result'][_:_+1]]
>>> for url in urls:
...     print(url)
...
Url1
Url2
Url3
Url4
Url5
Url6
Url7
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
urls = [e.split('::')[-1] for e in result['Result']]
print(*urls)
```

output:

```
Url1 Url2 Url3 Url4 Url5 Url6 Url7
```

if you want only the first nth urls to be assigned to some n variables you can use:

```
url1, url2, url3 = [e.split('::')[-1] for e in result['Result'][:3]]
```